# How to obtain the maximum integer value for $\frac{\tan \theta}{10}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, optimization

The problem is as follows:

> The diagram from below shows a cruiser which has departed from an
> allied shore. A nearby lighthouse is located on point $A$. Assume the
> height between the bottom of the lighthouse on $A$ to the top of the
> lighthouse $P$ is equal to $\textrm{10 m}$. The cruiser is located at
> $1.2\,km$ from the lighthouse ($MA=1.2\,km$). After advancing $1\,km$
> in a straight line the cruiser makes a stop on point $N$ to do
> maintenance and repairs. Assuming the amount of sailors which needs to
> be rescued is given by $\frac{12E}{7}$ where $E$ is the maximum
> integer value, which it can take $\frac{\tan \theta}{10}$ and $\angle
> > APN=\theta$, find the amount of people who will be rescued.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given on my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{48 sailors}\\
2.&\textrm{36 sailors}\\
3.&\textrm{24 sailors}\\
4.&\textrm{42 sailors}\\
\end{array}$

This problem I don't know how to approach it correctly. The thing which confuses me the most is how to make sure \tan\theta is maximum?

I do remember that:

If it mentions that \theta is acute then this means it lies in the first quadrant. Hence:

$0\leq \tan \theta < +\infty$

In short what it is asking is how to get maximimum integer value for:

$E=\frac{\tan\theta}{10}$

But given such condition it isn't very logical to find the maximum because it is on the positive infinity side. What to do next?.

I've attempted using derivatives, but it wouldn't make much sense as it would confirm that given this situation you can find the minimum:

$\tan\theta'=\sec^2\theta=\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$

And to equate the previous equation to zero would mean that the denominator has to be infinity.

So **what to do here?**. I don't know how to relate the other information provided. In other words the height of the lighthouse and the distance covered by the cruiser.

Can someone help me here please?.

Comment: @peterwhy Sorry, you're right it is $1.2\,km$. I'm updating the question to reflect this.

Comment: Are "the sailors which needs to be rescued" the same group as "the people who will be rescued"? Sometimes the latter is just a subset... or a superset.

Answer (score 0):

Triangle $ANM$ gives us: $AN < 2200$.

Triangle $PNA$ gives us: $\tan \theta <220$.

$E = \frac{\tan \theta}{10}< 22$.

$E_{max}=...$

$\text{Amount}=...$

Can you finish?

Comment: Well, I suppose that would meant $E_{max}=21$, hence $\frac{(12)(21)}{7}=24$. Which it would be the number of sailors. It seems that you used the triangle inequality to relate it with the maximum for that function. But the part which it remains unattended from my question is. *Why the approach using $\tan\theta$ didn't worked?* and *why derivatives doesn't work in this case?* can you please help me to explain this part?.